# Saving data sent from client to server into a file has invalid characters

Tags: c, client-server, client, server, file-transfer

I am trying to send a file containing strings from a client to a server, and then have the server save the results received. So far, I have managed to send the data from the client to the server, but when the server saves the results in a text file, it contains invalid characters which are unreadable.

The contents of the file has around 10 lines of zeros like below (and is highlighted in red) with random characters in between:

```
POST /apikey=json&command={"Parameter" : "Value"}\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00ð|\00\00\00\00|'^O\00\00ÿÿÿÿ
```

I did a bit of research, and tried using binary mode: (fp = fopen( "testfile.txt" , "wb" ); but that didn't solve it.

**Server**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define PORT "3490"  // the port users will be connecting to

#define BACKLOG 10     // how many pending connections queue will hold

void sigchld_handler(int s)
{
    while(waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG) > 0);
}

// get sockaddr, IPv4 or IPv6:
void *get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa)
{
    if (sa->sa_family == AF_INET) {
        return &(((struct sockaddr_in*)sa)->sin_addr);
    }

    return &(((struct sockaddr_in6*)sa)->sin6_addr);
}

int main(void)
{
    int sockfd, new_fd;  // listen on sock_fd, new connection on new_fd
    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
    struct sockaddr_storage their_addr; // connector's address information
    socklen_t sin_size;
    struct sigaction sa;
    int yes=1;
    char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    int rv;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE; // use my IP

    if ((rv = getaddrinfo(NULL, PORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
        return 1;
    }

    // loop through all the results and bind to the first we can
    for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype,
                p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
            perror("server: socket");
            continue;
        }

        if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes,
                sizeof(int)) == -1) {
            perror("setsockopt");
            exit(1);
        }

        if (bind(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
            close(sockfd);
            perror("server: bind");
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    if (p == NULL)  {
        fprintf(stderr, "server: failed to bind\n");
        return 2;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(servinfo); // all done with this structure

    if (listen(sockfd, BACKLOG) == -1) {
        perror("listen");
        exit(1);
    }

    sa.sa_handler = sigchld_handler; // reap all dead processes
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
    if (sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sa, NULL) == -1) {
        perror("sigaction");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("server: waiting for connections...\n");

    while(1) {  // main accept() loop
        sin_size = sizeof their_addr;
        new_fd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &sin_size);
        if (new_fd == -1) {
            perror("accept");
            continue;
        }

        inet_ntop(their_addr.ss_family,
            get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)&their_addr),
            s, sizeof s);
        printf("server: got connection from %s\n", s);

{
        char buf[1000];
        ssize_t len;

        len = recv(new_fd, buf, sizeof(buf) - 1, 0);
        if (len > 0) {
                buf[len] = '\0';
                printf("buffer: %s len: %d\n\n", buf, (int)len);

                        /* save to file */              
                    FILE *fp;
                    fp = fopen( "testfile.txt" , "wb" ); //b for binary
                    fwrite(buf, 1, sizeof buf, fp);
                    fclose(fp);

            }
    }



        if (!fork()) { // this is the child process
            close(sockfd); // child doesn't need the listener
            if (send(new_fd, "I received your message\n", 23, 0) == -1)
                perror("send");
            close(new_fd);
            exit(0);
        }
        close(new_fd);  // parent doesn't need this
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Client**

```
#include <stdio.h> /* printf, sprintf */
#include <stdlib.h> /* read, write, close */
#include <string.h> /* memcpy, memset */
#include <sys/socket.h> /* socket, connect */
#include <netinet/in.h> /* struct sockaddr_in, struct sockaddr */
#include <netdb.h> /* struct hostent, gethostbyname */
#include <unistd.h>

void error(const char *msg) { perror(msg); exit(0); }

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    /* first what are we going to send and where are we going to send it? */
    int portno =        3490; /* 3490 or 8080 */
    char *host =        "192.168.1.65"; /* localhost: 127.0.0.1 or 192.168.1.65 */
    char *message_fmt = "POST /apikey=%s&command=%s HTTP/1.0\n\n";

    struct hostent *server;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    int sockfd, bytes, sent, received, total;
    char message[1024],response[4096];

    //if (argc < 3) { puts("Parameters: <apikey> <command>"); exit(0); }

    /* fill in the parameters */
    sprintf(message,message_fmt,argv[1],argv[2]);
    printf("Request:\n%s\n",message);

    /* create the socket */
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) error("ERROR opening socket");

    /* lookup the ip address */
    server = gethostbyname(host);
    printf("ip address: %s\n\n", host);
    if (server == NULL) error("ERROR, no such host");

    /* fill in the structure */
    memset(&serv_addr,0,sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    memcpy(&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,server->h_addr,server->h_length);

    /* connect the socket */
    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
        error("ERROR connecting");

    /* send the request */

/********************************* reading input data and converting into JSOn format ***********************/
   FILE *file = stdin;
    char a[50], b[50];
        while(1 == fscanf(file," %[^,]",a) ) /* Read data until a comma is detected, */
            {

               fgetc( file ); // Ignore , character

               fscanf(file," %[^,]",b); /* Read data until a comma is detected, */
               fgetc( file ); // Ignore , character

        printf("{\"%s\" : \"%s\"}\n",a,b); /* Display results into {"A":"B"} format */
    }


   ///sprintf(message,message_fmt,a[0],b[0]);


    //total = strlen(message);
//printf("sending message %d\n",total);
sprintf(a, message_fmt,"json","{\"Parameter\" : \"Value\"}\n");
//total = strlen(a); // this takes the value of 'a' eg: 1, 2, 3, 4, - 'a' will be 1,3 while b=2,4
total = strlen(message);
    sent = 0;
    do {
        bytes = write(sockfd,a+sent,total-sent);
        if (bytes < 0)
            error("ERROR writing message to socket");
        if (bytes == 0)
            break;
        sent+=bytes;
    } while (sent < total); //while (sent < 0);
    printf("Post request sent \n");

    //receive the response
    printf("Receiving response \n");
    memset(response,0,sizeof(response));
    total = sizeof(response)-1;
    received = 0;
    do {
        bytes = read(sockfd,response-received,total-received);
        if (bytes < 0)
            error("ERROR reading response from socket");
        if (bytes == 0)
            break;
        received+=bytes;
    } while(received < total); //while (received < 0);
    printf("Response received\n");

    if (received == total)
        error("ERROR storing complete response from socket");

    /* close the socket */
    close(sockfd);

    /* process response */
    printf("\nServer Response:\n%s\n\n",response);

    return 0;
}
```

**Summary**
1- Send a string (eg. Hello World) from client to server
2- Server reads the string, saves it into a text file
3- But text file has invalid characters and zeroes instead

Comment: fwrite(buf, 1, sizeof buf, fp); - why are you writing 'sizeof buf' bytes when you already know that you have received 'len' bytes?

Comment: @MartinJames Is that wrong? I was following the parameters of using fwrite().

Comment: Yes, it's wrong - the buffer might not be full and so you will be writing more data than you have received.

Comment: @MartinJames Thank you, kind sir. Your suggestion worked successfully and made the random characters disappear!

Comment: OK, great!   I'll promote it to an answer, then:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont write 'sizeof buf' bytes to the file - the buffer may not be completely full of data.  Use the 'len' value instead that was returned by the recv() call.